# Routing issues, UDR to use NVA(linux) as proxy

Tags: azure

I'm trying to setup a fairly simple network to be able to monitor traffic from a subnet using a UDR and running into issues. I'm clearly overlooking something and a push in the right direction would be very helpful.

I have two NSGs defined, one for each subnet. Which are standard rules.

I have a UDR, which is assigned to the 10.1.1.0/24 subnet (subnet 2 we'll say). The rules in the UDR are have a route defined to use a NVA which is located in subnet1(eg. 10.1.0.4).

As of right now, 10.1.0.4 interface has forwarding enabled and also within the vm, which is an ubuntu server machine. It does not see any of the traffic from anything but itself. Machine have internet access through the system routes(default).

Virtual Network:
Subnet1: 10.1.0.0/24 (3 hosts right now)
  - 10.1.0.4
  - 10.1.0.5
  - 10.1.0.6
Subnet2: 10.1.1.0/24 (3 hosts as well)
  - 10.1.1.4
  - 10.1.1.5
  - 10.1.1.6

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want to forward traffic from subnet 1 to subnet 2 via UDR?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to have any traffic leaving a vm in subnet2 and trying to reach 0.0.0.0/0 to have use the virtual appliance 10.0.0.4 as a proxy. So that I can use the linux machine with 10.1.0.4 to log the traffic.